# Send response back to frontend on reader.on('end')

Tags: node.js

I'm streaming a response from the backend, but when the stream ends, I need to perform additional functions such as saving it in the backend and then sending a request back to the frontend. To put it briefly, the frontend is calling this route, and at the end of the stream, I want to pass token:id as a response back to the frontend.

```
const response = ResponsefromServer

const sseStream = new SseStream(req);
    sseStream.pipe(res);

    const reader = response.body;
    

    reader.on('data', (data: any) => 
      sseStream.write({ data });
    });

    reader.on('end', async () => {
      console.log("End of stream");
      sseStream.end(); // Close the SSE stream when the data stream ends

// Now, once the stream finishes, I want to store some values in my database, retrieve a token, and send it back to the frontend.

}
```

Comment: You'd need to make another request, probably a POST request, to send the data to the server.

Comment: From the frontend, I'm calling this route. Initially, the response is sent through streaming. I'm wondering if I can pass an additional value through reader. on('end'), Once the streaming is compete. Somehow, I need to send this response as part of the initial response only.

Comment: Server-side event streams are uni-directional, they only go from the server to the client, there's no built-in means to respond to messages with those. You'll either need to switch to websockets (bi-directional, but you may not be able to depending on the server and hosting), or you'll need to use traditional http requests to send data to the server.